# Is it possible for Matlab to resolve a symbol as an arbitrary value?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am using MATLAB in my engineering studies to solve Laplace transforms.

For example I have the code:

```
EDU>> syms R C Vs s
EDU>> vc0 = 0;
EDU>> Vcs = (Vs/s+R*C*vc0)/(R*C*s+1);
EDU>> vct = ilaplace(Vcs,s);
EDU>> pretty(simple(vct))

            /    s  \ 
Vs - Vs exp| -  --- | 
            \   C R /
```

Now I would like to plot the function vct which is the inverse LaPlace transform of Vcs, however, I don't particularly care about the specific values of C, R, and Vs. I just want to see a generic case.

Is there any way to set assumptions such as that if I were to use the command:

```
ezplot(vct)
```

That it would assume C, R, and Vs are arbitrary constant values and generate the graph as a function of the single variable s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure whether ezplot can handle more than two variables at the time.
perhaps you can try [subs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html?refresh=true) to resolve the symbol before plotting.

for example,
`>>`double(subs(vct,{'Vs','R','C','s'},{2,1,2,3}))
`>>`1.5537

Comment: I was hoping there was an easier way to do this for an arbitrary magnitude, but using subs will work. It does require some knowledge of the parameters that are being substituted. Thanks for the response!